# Email confirmation on ASP.NET Core and Angular 7 (ussing IdentityUser)

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, angular7

I want to implement email confirmation to my registration process,
I'm using Angular 7 as client, I tried to implement it myself through tutorials but most of them for MVC...
I want to know what do I need exactly and how its should work...

here is my code:

ASP core:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<object> PostAppUser(AppUserModel model)
        {
            var result = await _userService.Register(model);

            if (result != null)
                return Ok(result);
            else
                return BadRequest(new { message = "Register failed! Please try again later" });
        }

  public async Task<object> Register(AppUserModel model)
        {
            if (model.SpecialCode == _appSettings.Special_Code)
                model.Role = "admin";
            else
                model.Role = "customer";

            var appUser = new AppUser()
            {
                UserName = model.UserName,
                Email = model.Email,
                FullName = model.FullName,
            };

            try
            {
                var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(appUser, model.Password);
                await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(appUser, model.Role);

                return result;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Startup:

```
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
    services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    services.AddDbContext<AuthContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("IdentityConnection")));
    services.AddDefaultIdentity<AppUser>()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthContext>();
```

Angular:

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm, userName: string) {
    this.userService.login(form.value).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
        this.toastr.success('Welcome ' + userName + '!' , 'Authentication granted');
      },
      (err: any) => {
        if (err.status === 400) {
          this.toastr.error('Incorrect User name of Password!', 'Authentication failed');
          form.reset();
        } else {
          this.toastr.error('Our servers is down at the moment', 'Try again later');
          form.reset();
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you run the code ? What is the error ? Please be more clear about what you need

Comment: There isnt an error, I just want to know what do I need in order to make the email verfication...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the email confirmation into your application, you should:

1. Add instruction to Send email confirmation (with the link) into your registration method.

   var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(YourUserEntity);

It will generate a token to confirm the email of your user.
 - Create a callback link for your angular application, for example:

```
var callBackUrl = "http://localhost:4200/Profile/ConfirmEmail?userId="+usrIdentity.Id + "&token=" + code;
```

And then , send the callBackUrl to the user email.

2. Into your angular application, you should create a route for the callBackUrl, once the user click on the link sent on the email.

You should send a request to your WebApi with the userId and the token (On The link) to confirm the user email and check if the token is valid, to do that you must implement a new post method on your controller named (ConfirmUserEmail), and bellow it, implement The following instruction:

```
 var dbUserResult = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(user.IdIdentityNavigation.Email);

if (dbUserResult != null)
{
                var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(dbUserResult, confirmUserEntity.token);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                { \* Implement Your business logic here /* }

}
```